# How to disable a test.php file without deleting it?

Tags: testing

In D8 I have failing automated tests due to a depend modules code problems. The tests should not be deleted as they will be reinstated when the other module is fixed. I tried changing the test function names to start with something other than 'test' but this gave the warning "there are no tests in this class" and failed just the same. The tests are based on  BrowserTestBase.

I want to commit a change so that the rest our automated tests can run, as this problem is making it appear that every patch fails. I do not want to comment out the entire test file - there must be a better way to highlight the fact that these tests should not be run when the rest of the test suite is

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by editing the info file, in Drupal 7.

```
name = myModule 
description = My module  
core = 7.x
testing_api = 2.x // remove this line
files[] = myModule.module
files[] = myModule.install
files[] = tests/myModule.test // remove this line
```

I am not sure in the case of Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks but it is different in Drupal8. I have many test files and they do not need to be listed in the .info.yml file. I still need the tests to run for the majority of the 25 test files, but just not the three test files which depend on the failing 3rd-party module.

I got round it by renaming the test files from .php to .txt. Then when the 3rd-party module (Rules) is running again I can rename the files back again.